# How to enable brace enclosed initializer lists for my own collection class?

Tags: c++, collections, c++11, std, initializer-list

Given this example class:

```
template<typename T>
class ExampleContainer
{
private:        
  std::map<T, int> _objects;
  int _sum;

public:
  ExampleContainer()
    : _objects(), _sum(0)
  {
  }

  void Add(T obj, int add)
  {
    _objects[obj] = add; // yes this is bad, but it's an example.
    _sum += add;
  }
};
```

What is needed to be able to use it like this:

```
ExampleContainer<char*> _rarities =
{
  { "One", 600 },
  { "Two", 200 },
  { "Three", 50 },
  { "Four", 10 },
  { "Five", 1 },
};
```

I know it must be somehow possible, because I can initialize a std::map like that already.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a constructor accepting an `std::initializer_list` to your `ExampleContainer` class:

```
ExampleContainer(std::initializer_list<typename std::map<T, int>::value_type> l)
    :
    _objects(l)
{
}
```

This will be invoked every time you use the curly braces to initialize the object, as in this case:

```
ExampleContainer<char*> _rarities =
{
    ...
};
```

This way, each entry within the curly braces will become an element of the initializer list.

Since the underlying type of the initializer list here is `std::map<T, int>::value_type`, temporary objects of that type will be constructed from the values you provide:

```
ExampleContainer<char*> _rarities =
{
    { "One", 600 },     // Each of these entires will cause the creation of
    { "Two", 200 },     // a temporary object of type:
    { "Three", 50 },    //     std::pair<char* const, int>
    { "Four", 10 },     // that will become an element of the initializer
    { "Five", 1 },      // list received by the constructor.
};
```

Also note, that the conversion from a string literal to `char*` is *deprecated* in C++03 and **invalid** in C++11 (string literals have type `char const[]` in C++11). Thus, you may want to give your variable `_rarities` the type `ExampleContainer<char const*>` instead (C array types decay to pointer types).

**UPDATE:**

As correctly pointed out by @LightnessRacesInOrbit in the comments, this approach is dangerous in case you are not going to use just string literals in your container (that's something I kind of assumed from your example, but in fact nothing implies it). It is a better idea to use `std::string` instead (so you should declare `_rarities` as `ExampleContainer<std::string>`).

Comment: thank you for the precise and elaborate answer. Do not fear, in reality I use ExampleContainer with ints/enums, but the for example's sake I used char* =)

Comment: More likely `std::string`. You can't really "store" C-strings and if you try you'll probably have nasty ownership bugs.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Good point. But that should be OK as long as he's using just string literals, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Agreed. Will mention it in the answer.

Comment: not only is the conversion of a string literal (not of a `const char*`!) deprecated in C++03, but it is absent in C++11.